# Django filter manytomanyfield exclude objects that are related to another model

Tags: python, django

I have 2 models, `File` and `Fileset`:

```
class File(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, db_index=True)


class Fileset(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, db_index=True)
    files = models.ManyToManyField(File, related_name='fileset_files')
```

I want to filter `File` objects that are not related to any other `Fileset`

#### Problem

Consider that I have 3 `File` objects:

- File1
- File2
- File3

I have 2 `Fileset` objects:

- Fileset1 (is related to File1)
- Fileset2 (is related to File1, File2 & File3)

When I try the query:

```
File.objects
.filter(fileset_files__fileset_name='Fileset2')  # all files from Fileset2
.exclude(fileset_files=Fileset.objects.get(fileset_name='Fileset1'))  # exclude the files that are in Fileset1
```

This returns File2 & File3 like I want.

How do I make this work when I have, lets say 20 different Filesets? How should I filter for Files that are in other Filesets when I have multiple Filesets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using `annotate` and `Count` like this:

```
from django.db.models import Count

File.objects
.annotate(fileset_count=Count('fileset_files__uuid'))
.filter(fileset_count=1)
```